# Crossing european borders by land

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, borders

I'm an American in Ireland, I'm going to be entering the UK and then France by land. I heard if traveling by bus or car many European borders don't have custom stops when entering. How do I get my entry and exit stamps for my schengen visa?

Comment: @Tenzin Tharpa You won’t have a Schengen visa - as a US citizen you may enter for up to 90 days for tourist and business purposes without a visa. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/France.html

Comment: There are no *customs* controls between the UK and France, but there are *immigration* controls, and that's how you'll get your stamps.  But there's no *land* border between the UK and France!

Answer (score 5):

You will most definitely have an immigration check on exit from the UK and on entry into France. For the Eurostar train, you will do both in the UK (French officials are allowed to do this). Otherwise, your Schengen visa will be check as you enter France. [**EDIT**: Not correct; see comment below. Only arrival by air is checked in France; other types of transport from England will be checked at departure.]

What you have heard about is the Schengen Zone. Many European countries have abolished immigration and customs checks at their shared land borders, so going by bus/train from France to Germany, Belgium, Spain, Switzerland, will be as uneventful as going from New York to Connecticut.

[**SECOND EDIT**: I missed the OP’s statement that he is an American. If he truly is a USA citizen, he does not need a Schengen visa at all for a tourist or business visit.]

Comment: Minor correction: Excluding air, all French entry checks when travelling from the UK to France take place in the UK. The French entry stamps read "LFT Londres" if you take the Eurostar, "LFT Cheriton" if you take the Euroshuttle (including driving/coaches) and "BCNJ Douvres" if you take the ferry.

Comment: It's important to note that the UK and Ireland are _not_ in the Schengen area. But they have their own separate and distinct Common Travel Area.

Comment: And since you mentioned it, although not relevant for the question: Switzerland has customs checks on all their land borders.

Comment: The Swiss may stop trucks, but I’ve crossed the Swiss border by car and bicycle without being stopped, indeed, with the booths appearing unstaffed.